# Communication between Controllers in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

What is the right way to communicate between two Controller Classes in JavaFX?

*For example:*

```
public class Controller {

  @FXML
  private Label label;

  @FXML
  private void initialize(){
      label.setText("A Label");
  }

  public void setLabelText(String labelText){
      label.setText(labelText);
  }

}
```

How can I call the method *setLabelText()* from another Controller Class without making it static?

Comment: instantiate a object of type controller, with its constructor method. And them controller.setLabelText.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)